# General error: 1364 with STRICT_TRANS_TABLES disabled

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-mode

I have a Mariadb 10.2.26 server, with "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" mode disabled. Only mode enabled is "NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION". But even like this, I am getting "General error: 1364 Field '' doesn't have a default value". Does anyone have any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE..` for the concerned table.

Comment: When do you get this error (insert,update?) and what is your insert,update statement?

Comment: I get it on a simple insert query. Create table and statement I guess are not relevant here, as it is an old table with more then 100 fields, a lot of them without default values and not nullable. That's why I am trying to avoid this error by sql_mode settings. The issue is why I am still getting error 1364 even with STRICT_TRANS_TABLES disabled.

Comment: if your solution is to modify sql_mode to make a query work you choose the very wrong approach.. Also a disabled `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` (strict mode) is asking for trouble..

Comment: I agree. But it's a big old database I have to work upon, with almost 400 tables with more than 2000 fields in that situation. I rather take this approach for now to complete my project than spend weeks to fix the db first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small sample of the "incompatible changes" made over the years.

> ----- 2014-09-25 5.7.5 Milestone 15 -- SQL Mode Notes -- Incompatible Change -----
>
> These SQL mode changes were made:
>
> ```
> Strict SQL mode for transactional storage engines ([STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables))
> ```
>
> is now enabled by default.
>
> ```
> Implementation of the [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)
> ```
>
> SQL mode has been made more sophisticated, to no longer reject
>   deterministic queries that previously were rejected.
>
> ```
>     MySQL now recognizes when a nonaggregated selected column is functionally dependent on (uniquely determined by) GROUP BY columns.
>
>     MySQL has an extension to standard SQL that permits references in the HAVING clause to aliased expressions in the select list.
> ```
>
> Previously, enabling
>   [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)
>   disables this extension, thus requiring the HAVING clause to be
>   written using unaliased expressions. This restriction has been lifted
>   so that the HAVING clause can refer to aliases regardless of whether
>   [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)
>   is enabled.
>
> ```
> In consequence, [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)
> ```
>
> is now enabled by default, to prohibit nondeterministic queries
>   containing expressions not guaranteed to be uniquely determined within
>   a group.
>
> ```
> The changes to the default SQL mode result in a default [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode)
> ```
>
> system variable value with these modes enabled:
>   [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by),
>   [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables),
>   [NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_engine_substitution).
>
> ```
> The [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)
> ```
>
> mode is now included in the modes comprised by the
>   [ANSI](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi)
>   SQL mode.
>
> ```
> A new function, ANY_VALUE(), is available that can be used to force MySQL to accept queries that it thinks should be rejected with
> ```
>
> [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)
>   enabled. The function return value and type are the same as the return
>   value and type of its argument, but the function result is not checked
>   for the
>   [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)
>   SQL mode.
>
> If you find that having
>   [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)
>   enabled causes queries for existing applications to be rejected,
>   either of these actions should restore operation:
>
> ```
> If it is possible to modify an offending query, do so, either so that nondeterministic nonaggregated columns are functionally dependent
> ```
>
> on GROUP BY columns, or by referring to nonaggregated columns using
>   [ANY_VALUE()](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value).
>
> ```
> If it is not possible to modify an offending query (for example, if it is generated by a third-party application), set the sql_mode
> ```
>
> system variable at server startup to not enable
>   [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).
>
> For more information about SQL modes and GROUP BY queries, see [Server
>   SQL
>   Modes](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html),
>   and [MySQL Handling of GROUP
>   BY](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).
>   (Bug #18486310)
>
> ----- 2014-03-31 5.7.4 Milestone 14 -- Functionality Added or Changed -- Incompatible Change -----
>
> The deprecated
>   [ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_error_for_division_by_zero),
>   [NO_ZERO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date),
>   and
>   [NO_ZERO_IN_DATE](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date)
>   SQL modes now do nothing. Instead, their previous effects are included
>   in the effects of strict SQL mode
>   ([STRICT_ALL_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables)
>   or
>   [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables)).
>   In other words, strict mode now means the same thing as the previous
>   meaning of strict mode plus the
>   [ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_error_for_division_by_zero),
>   [NO_ZERO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date),
>   and
>   [NO_ZERO_IN_DATE](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date)
>   modes. This change reduces the number of SQL modes with an effect
>   dependent on strict mode and makes them part of strict mode itself.
>
> To prepare for the SQL mode changes in this version of MySQL, it is
>   advisable before upgrading to read [SQL Mode Changes in MySQL
>   5.7](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-changes).
>   That discussion provides guidelines to assess whether your
>   applications will be affected by these changes.
>
> The deprecated
>   [ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_error_for_division_by_zero),
>   [NO_ZERO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date),
>   and
>   [NO_ZERO_IN_DATE](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date)
>   SQL modes are still recognized so that statements that name them do
>   not produce an error, but will be removed in a future version of
>   MySQL. To make advance preparation for versions of MySQL in which
>   these modes do not exist, applications should be modified to not refer
>   to those mode names.
>
> ----- 2014-03-27 5.6.17 General Availability -- SQL Mode Notes -- Incompatible Change -----
>
> The
>   [ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_error_for_division_by_zero),
>   [NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date),
>   and
>   [NO_ZERO_IN_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date)
>   SQL modes now are deprecated and setting the sql_mode value to include
>   any of them generates a warning. In MySQL 5.7, these modes do nothing.
>   Instead, their effects are included in the effects of strict SQL mode
>   ([STRICT_ALL_TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables)
>   or
>   [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables)).
>   The motivation for the change in MySQL 5.7 is to reduce the number of
>   SQL modes with an effect dependent on strict mode and make them part
>   of strict mode itself.
>
> To make advance preparation for an upgrade to MySQL 5.7, see [SQL Mode
>   Changes in MySQL
>   5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-changes).
>   That discussion provides guidelines to assess whether your
>   applications will be affected by the SQL mode changes in MySQL 5.7.
>
> ----- 2013-02-05 5.6.10 General Availability -- Bugs Fixed -- InnoDB -----
>
> During an [online
>   DDL](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_online_ddl)
>   operation, changing a column from nullable to NOT NULL could succeed
>   or fail differently depending on whether the [ALTER
>   TABLE](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)
>   statement used ALGORITHM=INPLACE or ALGORITHM=COPY. An operation with
>   ALGORITHM=COPY would succeed even if the column contained NULL values,
>   while an operation with ALGORITHM=INPLACE failed because of the
>   possibility that the column contained NULL values. Now, making a
>   column NOT NULL in combination with the ALGORITHM=INPLACE clause is
>   allowed, but only if the
>   [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode)
>   configuration option includes the
>   [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables)
>   or
>   [STRICT_ALL_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables)
>   setting. If the ALGORITHM clause is not specified with the [ALTER
>   TABLE](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)
>   statement, the online DDL operation will use ALGORITHM=INPLACE if
>   possible, or ALGORITHM=COPY if not. (Bug #15961327)
>
> ----- 2012-11-07 5.6.8 Release Candidate -- Installation Notes -- -----
>
> On Unix platforms, mysql_install_db now creates a default option file
>   named my.cnf in the base installation directory. This file is created
>   from a template included in the distribution package named
>   my-default.cnf. You can find the template in or under the base
>   installation directory. When started using mysqld_safe, the server
>   uses my.cnf file by default. If my.cnf already exists,
>   mysql_install_db assumes it to be in use and writes a new file named
>   my-new.cnf instead.
>
> With one exception, the settings in the default option file are
>   commented and have no effect. The exception is that the file changes
>   the
>   [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode)
>   system variable from its default of
>   [NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_engine_substitution)
>   to also include
>   [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables):
>
> sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
>
> This setting produces a server configuration that results in errors
>   rather than warnings for bad data in operations that modify
>   transactional tables. See [Server SQL
>   Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html).
>
> The my-default.cnf template replaces the older sample option files
>   (my-small.cnf, my-medium.cnf, and so forth), which are no longer
>   distributed.
>
> ----- 2004-12-01 5.0.2 -- Functionality Added or Changed -- -----
>
> Added
>   [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables),
>   [STRICT_ALL_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables),
>   [NO_ZERO_IN_DATE](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date),
>   [NO_ZERO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date),
>   [ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_error_for_division_by_zero),
>   and
>   [TRADITIONAL](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional)
>   SQL modes. The
>   [TRADITIONAL](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional)
>   mode is shorthand for all the preceding modes. When using mode
>   [TRADITIONAL](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional),
>   MySQL generates an error if you try to insert a wrong value in a
>   column. It does not adjust the value to the closest possible legal
>   value.
>
> ----- 2004-12-01 5.0.2 -- Functionality Added or Changed -- -----
>
> The compilation flag DONT_USE_DEFAULT_FIELDS was removed because you
>   can get the same behavior by setting the
>   [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode)
>   system variable to
>   [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables).
>
> ----- 2004-12-01 5.0.2 -- Functionality Added or Changed -- -----
>
> MySQL now remembers which columns were declared to have default
>   values. In
>   [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables)/[STRICT_ALL_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables)
>   mode, you now get an error if you do an
>   [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html)
>   without specifying all columns that don't have a default value. A side
>   effect of this is that when you do SHOW CREATE for a new table, you no
>   longer see a DEFAULT value for a column for which you didn't specify a
>   default value.